# How can supertype be contained in subtype without throwing any compile-time error?

Tags: java, generics, collections

if `List<Object>` contains `List<Integer>` than it is perfect But how could java allows the test of `List<Integer>` containing `List<Object>` without throwing any compile-time error.

**TestCase-1**

```
Object obj = "one";
List<Object> objs = Arrays.<Object>asList("one", 2, 3.14, 4);
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(2, 4);
assert objs.contains(obj); //Statement 1
assert objs.containsAll(ints); //Statement 2
assert !ints.contains(obj); //Statement 3 
assert !ints.containsAll(objs); //Statement 4
```

In above case statement 3 & 4 compile & run Successfully.So my doubts are :

1. How can Statement 3 & 4 be run as there should be a compile-time
   error?
2. Is it an error or there is some reason for providing such a
   contradictory support ?

Comment: Google: Java Generics Type Erasure

Comment: But why no compile time error

Comment: "`List<Integer>` is subtype of `List<Object>`" Wrong. "if `List<Object>` contains `List<Integer>` than it is perfect" What does "perfect" mean and why would this have anything to do with any subtype relationship between different lists?

Comment: @SebastianRedl How can it be a duplicate when that question is talking about Map and i m asking in case of List?

Comment: @Prateek Because the reason is exactly the same. There is little difference between `Collection.contains` and `Map.containsKey`.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Please see Peter Lawrey solution

Comment: "`List<Integer>` is subtype of `List<Object>`" No, it is not.

Answer (score 1):

> How can Statement 3 & 4 be run as there should be a compile-time error?

This is because `contains(object)` will take any object.

> Is it an error or there is some reason for providing such a contradictory support ?

Before Java had generics you could call contains(Object) and so you can today using code that was written before generics.

Comment: it means the above support is for backward compatibility.

Comment: @Prateek In short, yes. But since that can mean a lot of things (excuse a lot of sins) I prefer to give some explanation if I can ;)

Comment: @Prateek Those `Object` methods are one of the worst features of Collections and you can regularly find bugs that result from incomplete refactoring. :( [JSR-14](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=14) states the source backwards compatibility part but it does not say whether they where thinking about adding typesafe versions + keep the old ones deprecated for compatibility. I would have preferred that.

Comment: @zapl can you mention the same thing in answer. also can you correct my question, if something wrong in language

Answer (score 0):

This unfortunate decision had to be made for backward compatibility with Java 1.4 compiled code.

Without this, the 1.4 code would not have run in 1.5 environment at all without full recompile.

Answer (score 0):

From the JDK sources, java.util.List has the methods:

`boolean contains(Object o);
containsAll(Collection<?> c)`

So there isn't any compile time issue (any input you use in your code is correct).

As these methods don't use generics, there must be a reason deep inside the JDK maybe for back compatibility in some implementations / uses of List.

As you know, generics are only compile-time checks in Java so the runtime is just the same as if you were using `List<Object>`.